# How to hide table rows on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a SQL generated table which is written into html with response.write. The table has some recursion elements (child-parent), and each new level of recursion is captured by regarding that row with an incremental class tally (first level gets class=1, second level gets class=2, third level gets class=3, etc).

By default I have all rows which are not level=1 hidden, and upon user click to show the next level down (toggle). This part is working great as well, however if you show level 2, then show level 3, and then hide level 2...level 3 is still showing (which is not right). If a child class is hidden, then all parent classes should hide also.

I need upon mouse click, if toggling a class, go up one class and ensure that it is hidden and all others above it (regardless if visible or hidden), but still allow that parent class to be shown. Additionally, I never want level 1 to be hidden.

Here is my jQuery which isn't quite right (doesn't allow level 3 and higher to be displayed). What is wrong or what should my code be to get it working? I think I'm extremely close. I believe it toggles level 3 and then the code runs and hides it, not allowing me to see anything level 3 or higher.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#temp td').click(function () { 
        var clicked = $(this).text();
        var level = $(this).closest('tr').attr("class");
        $('tr[pn="' + clicked + '"]').toggle();

        var currentlevel = parseInt(level);    // on click sets recursion level to integer
        var nextlevel = currentlevel + 1; // on click sets recursion level to current level plus 1
        var maxlevel = parseInt($('.1').length - 3); // on click determines max level of recursion minus offset

        if (currentlevel > 1) { // skips this section if clicking on level 1
            if ($('.' + nextlevel + ':visible').length) { // checks if parents are visible
                for (nextlevel; nextlevel < maxlevel; nextlevel++) { // cycles through all parent classes above current level
                    $('.' + nextlevel).hide(); // sets parent to hide
                };
            };
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: Off topic: I'm inclined to disagree with your premise. Having rows recursively collapse often proves to be a frustrating user experience, requiring me to drill down to the same point several times in some cases.

Comment: On topic: It's generally not necessary to track levels of nesting to accomplish this. Simply use descendancy relationships to traverse the DOM. I'd be happy to help further with a JSFiddle demo (showing a sample HTML structure) to play with.

Comment: @Isherwood noted. it is a where-used viewer, so there will be a lot of rows and be confusing if the rows don't collapse down. intent is to search a part, see if it is used in some place, then leave or search something else.

Comment: I get that, but only the upper level need collapse to keep a clean UI, right?

Comment: @Isherwood you shouldn't be able to see the nested (indented) levels if the prior level is not visible.

Comment: You may want to provide an example of the HTML that is produced by your ASP

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nicho247/zsp231dy/

Comment: uhm... hide table rows.. on click.. 
@Nicho247 https://jsfiddle.net/zsp231dy/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#temp td').click(function () { 

        var clicked = $(this).text();
        var level = $(this).closest('tr').attr("class");
        $('tr[pn="' + clicked + '"]').toggle();

        var currentlevel = parseInt(level);
        var nextlevel = currentlevel + 1; 
        var maxlevel = parseInt($('.1').length - 3); 

        if ($('.' + nextlevel + ':visible').length) { 
        }else{
            for (nextlevel; nextlevel < maxlevel; nextlevel++) { 
                $('.' + nextlevel).hide(); 
            };
        };
    });
   });
```